# Onclick not working under Div tag

Tags: onclick, aspbutton

I have a Asp:Panel which is displayed as a popup using jquery. following is the code for Asp:panel

enter code here

```
div id="divPublishSelected" runat="server" visible="true" 
<asp:Panel ID="pnlPublishSelected"  Width="726px" runat="server"  >  

 <asp:Button ID="btnModalPublish" runat="server" Text="Publish" 
    width="95px" tyle="margin-left: 50px" 
    Height="25px" style="margin-left: 90px" onclick="btnModalPublish_Click1" 
        /> 
 <asp:Button ID="btnModalCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" Width="100px" 
    Height="25px" style="margin-left: 90px"  /> 

 </asp:Panel>
 </div>
```

The following is the jquery

```
   $(document).ready(function () {<br>
    $("#divPublishSelected").dialog({ autoOpen: false });<br>
    $("#<%=btnPublishSelected.ClientID%>").click(<br>
 function () {<br>
 $('#modalBackground').css({ opacity: 0.2, 'width': $(document).width(), 'height':                  <    <br>$(document).height() });<br>
  $('body').css({ 'overflow': 'hidden' });<br>
  $("#divPublishSelected").dialog('open')<br>

   return false;<br>
 });<br>
    $("#<%=btnModalCancel.ClientID%>").click(<br>
 function () {<br>


  $("#divPublishSelected").dialog('close')
 return false;
})
  });

</script>
<B>
```

The onclick method of the asp:button is not working.what could be the reason

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been solved now add enablevalidation=false in the button it will fire the event